# Filter data from MySQL using WHERE or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

In terms of performance, what's better between select all rows from a table and then filter the results with PHP, or filter the query directly using `WHERE` (multiple conditions) ?

Comment: Definitely WHERE. A database has special code to filter data like index tables and so on.

Comment: You're better off letting the database do that. You supply one SQL query versus many lines of PHP to do the filtering. Also consider that with a database, it can cache the SQL WHERE result. With SELECT ALL and PHP filterihg, every time a visitor hits your website you have to  deal with all the records and filter it yourself when you don't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using where condition is the best choice because this query will run faster that the first one.
Indexes on the fields that appear in WHERE or GROUP BY or ORDER BY clauses are most of the time useful.
Loading all data before filter is better that loading the filtered data :)

Comment: This is generally true - but not true for **every** scenario, e.g. http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/23/digg-4000-performance-increase-by-sorting-in-php-rather-than.html (but of course, we're not all Facebook)

Answer (score 1):

Its better to fetch data using WHERE clause because it will boost your system performance in terms of time and load.
Because if you use **"select * "** then that will consume more time and after that you have to waste further time to use that records as per your needs. So again you have to write code for that.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` is the better solution. If you would like to do it in `php` you have to load all data from database before you can filter the data. 
In database you can add an index which makes the filtering performence better.

Answer (score 1):

I think it also depends on how many time you need to call that mysql query to fetch result.

SO if you call that only once then yes **WHERE** clause is better solution

**But** if it require you to make multiple server call to fetch filterd data using mysql query then I think the first one approach will be better than this I.e **Select all rows from a table and then filter the results with PHP**

I hope it help you :)